# How to get a class selected by the user?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I had read some posts about it, but not sure if some is the answer that i've been looking for. I want to get a class selected by user input and check if it is on a list. I don't wanna create if, switch or Map (I'll use lots of classes). I'm trying to do this in few lines, if it's possible at all. Thanks!

```
public boolean isClassDefined(ArrayList<GeometricObject> geoObjects) {
    Class<?> classDefinedByUser=null;
    try {
        classDefinedByUser = Class.forName("Square");
        //as if user has typed "Square", being "class Square extends GeometricObject"
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mission.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    for (GeometricObject geo : geoObjects) {
        //here is where i don't know what to do
        //I want to create a if to check if there is an object (of the class
        //defined by the user) initialized into ArrayList "geoObjects"
        //I don't want to use lots of ifs
        if (geo instanceof classDefinedByUser.getClass()) {
            //if exists a Square type object, return true
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Class.isInstance` to check whether an object that you have **is** an instance of a class.

Your check should be:

```
if(classDefinedByUser.isInstance(geo))
```

Just note that this method will return `false` if `geo == null` (even if it's supposed to be an instance of the class)